# Etiquette: what to do if an accepted answer isn't rewarded with the bounty on that question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, bounties

I was wondering about the proper etiquette if an accepted answer (even if with no upvote) to a question with an open bounty isn't rewarded with the bounty reputation.

In this particular case, I answered this question

[Intel and AT&T assembly syntax highlighting in TextMate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859274/intel-and-att-assembly-syntax-highlighting-in-textmate/)

and the answer was accepted.

There was a +50 bounty on this question (by someone who wasn't the user asking it), but the bounty expired and I wasn't awarder with the bounty reputation.

My question is: should I have had contacted the bounty opener before the bounty expired?

Or it would have been considered impolite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to [ChrisF's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69899/etiquette-what-to-do-if-an-accepted-answer-isnt-rewarded-with-the-bounty-on-tha/69901#69901), I'm not sure that it would have been impolite to contact that person.

It's true that your answer might not have helped the user who added the bounty or he may have forgotten about it entirely, but a single comment notification reply to one of their comments (if possible) isn't going to take up much of his or her time.

Perhaps if the message was *"give me teh bountiez!"*, then yes, that would be impolite.  But contacting that person and asking them if your solution satisfied the requirements of the bounty or if there was some other way you could help them would have been the polite thing to do.

Why else would he add a bounty if he weren't looking for help?

Comment: +1. In 99.99999999% of cases people simply don't realize that they need to award the bounty separately.

Comment: Of course my message wouldn't have been "give me teh bountiez!" (if nothing else, because I would never write 'teh' and 'bountiez' :P), just a gently reminder. Anyway, thanks for all your help (I'm kinda new here, I still don't understand the right behavior that I'm supposed to have).

Comment: @mcapobianco I've been here for 18 months and I'm still new around here...

Answer (score 5):

No — personally I think it would be impolite.

While your answer helped the original poster, there may be something missing that doesn't help the person who assigned the bounty. They might be looking for a more efficient solution (or whatever). So they are well within their rights to not assign the bounty. They would have got notifications from the system that their bounty was about to expire.

They could have forgotten about it or not logged back into the site at the right time to see the notification of course.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Seems like there is more consensus on the opposite side... I'd like to know what you think about the other answer.

Comment: @m.capobianco - personally I wouldn't, but if the consensus is the other way then I can live with that.

Comment: I see. Thank you for sharing your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

The one time I offered a bounty, it took a long time to get an answer, and the bounty was about to expire when I got a good one.  If I'd been distracted, I might have missed awarding it.

I wasn't going to award a bounty for an answer that wasn't useful (I already had one of those on the question), but I did want to award it for a useful answer.

If you can contact the person offering the bounty, and remind them that it's going to expire and suggest they review the answers, including yours, I don't think that would be out of line.  Demanding the bounty clearly would be.

Answer (score -1):

I would say "it doesn't hurt to remind the bounty poster because they probably forgot".

I would forget. Please remind me. A simple comment of `@drachenstern does this suffice to reward the bounty` would be fine by me.

Comment: Why is a comment better than the current top bar reminder, *and* the current email reminder?

Comment: Because I didn't know that those were options (it emails you when a bounty award period is about to be up?)? Because I might not log into the site in question, but I'll see the notification on the MultiCollider no matter the site it's on?